# searching large arrays in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, algorithm

I have two very large `NSMutableArray` of strings containing more than 40k records each. I have to take each element from one array and sort that string into another array then make a new array which conatins only those records that are in both array.  I have implemented the following code which take too much time as well as a lot of memory space also (crash in device). Are there any ways to solve this problem in a more efficient manner.

```
// _perArray and listArray contains   more then 30K records each
for(NSString *gak in _perArray){
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[c] %@",gak];
    NSArray *results = [listArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if(results.count>0){
        [_resultArray addObject:results[0]];

    }
}
```

Comment: One word - database.

Comment: yes a array of one word.. Eample- aa,abc,abcs,asd.... etc

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood. I'm telling you that you need to use a database. Putting all the data in an array is a bad solution.

Comment: please explain i have to make a sqllit Database?  i have a text file which contains  all records  and from that text file i am  creating array.

Comment: Yes, replace your text file with a database.

Comment: i can explain u complete  situation i have make all permutation of a string link abc(abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba) and search that all permutation string in a text file it is exist or not. my code is work for 6 character but when it work for 7 or 8 character it takes too much time and memory.

Comment: @rmaddy according to you i have to create two ssqlite table one for permutation and other for text file and run sql query to fetch common records....

Comment: This doesn't sound like the best way. My gut feeling is that you should never need to store a full permutation of a number of letters, either in a text file or a database. Do you mind disclosing what's the use of this?

Comment: i have got this question for a completion they  want efficient program for that works  in iPhone .(frankly  i don't know what the use ) but i have to do only for competition

Comment: @JoeSmith +1 The solution should be a more intelligent to check for the permutations without calculating them in advance.

Comment: @AmitGupta Please clarify, because your comments are contra dictionary. Do you have to cheek for the complete permutations or for partial permutations, too. I. e.: If you have the word `bad`, obviously `bda` is a permutation, but `ab` and `da`, too? What is, if the source contains double letters as in `good`?

Comment: abc(abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba) if a string length is 3 all permutation whose length is also 3

Comment: This sounds like a typical "test" to see how you would approach tasks that involve large datasets where simple linear searches aren't feasible (as you have found). While in "the real world" the data may be in some form of database, that isn't what you have been given. You can convert the list to be searched into a graph which can be searched reasonably efficiently - this is what an index in a database would be - then simply permute each input word and search. As an optimisation you could add the completed permutations to a set so you don't search them again (consider 'cat' and 'act')

Comment: A further optimisation would be to remove the matched word from the list to be searched - once an anagram of "act" has matched "cat" there is no need to compare it again

Comment: @AmitGupta Can you give us a miniature version of your starting dataset?

Comment: I'm confused.  The above code is not sorting anything.  It's merely repeatedly scanning, using a relatively inefficient scheme to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Use binary search**

1. index sort one array (the one with less records)

   - this will enable the usage of binary searching
   - sort the lesser array just to need less memory for index array
2. loop through the second array

   - for each record binary search in the first array
   - if found add record to output array
   - do not forget to preallocate the output array to avoid reallocation slowdowns

What it means:

- Let `N,M` be the array sizes where `N<=M`
- naive approach is `O(N.M)`
- this approach (depending on used sort) leads to `O(N.log(N).log(M))`

**Sort both arrays and use single pass incremental search**

- the complexity will lead to something like `O((N.log(N))+(M.log(M))+M)`
- which in therms of complexity turns to `O(M.log(M))`

So:

1. index sort booth arrays
2. loop through `M`

   - increment index for array with lesser record
3. if match found add it to output array

To be more specific bullet 2 will be something like this (if arrays are sorted ascending):

```
// variables
string m[M],n[N],o[N]; // your arrays any string type with overloaded <,== operators
int M,N,O;               // arrays sizes
int ixm[M],ixn[N];      // indexes for index sort
int i,j;

// bullet 2
for (i=0,j=0,O=0;;)
 {
 if (m[ixm[i]]==n[ixn[j]]) { o[O]=m[ixm[i]]; O++; }
 if (m[ixm[i]]< n[ixn[j]]) { if (i<M) i++; else { if (j<N) j++; else break; }}
  else                     { if (j<N) j++; else { if (i<M) i++; else break; }}
 }
```

If you encode the string comparisons right you can do booth if conditions with single comparison

**[notes]**

- if you do not want to use any of these approaches then there is also another way
- you can add flag to one array telling you if it is already used
- if it is skip the use of it during your comparisons
- that will speed up your naive approach about 2 times
- from `M.N` string comparisons you will need to do just `M.N/2`
- If you have too big data chunks to fit in memory
- then segmentate both arrays to some size fit to memory/Cache/...
- and first index sort all segments
- then do one of the above approach on all segments combinations
- the only thing you need to add is checking if `O[]`  does not already contain added string
- if you arrays does not have multiples of the same string then this is not the case
- otherwise keep `O[]` sorted or index sorted
- and check by binary search ...
- this segmentation will be speeded up with the used flag significantly

Comment: @AmitGupta finished edditing

Answer (score 0):

Always balance the performance issues with the frequency this code path is called. Going the database route might introduce a whole new set of issues to deal with while simply performing the sort in the background, and cutting down the size of the array first might be good enough.

#### Remove the duplicates first using NSMutableSet

Add all the objects, `NSString` in this case, to an NSMutableSet. This will eliminate the duplicates. Then sort the remaining objects.

```
NSArray *array1;
NSArray *array2;
NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:array1];
[mutableSet addObjectsFromArray:array2];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = nil; // You'll need to create a sort descriptor.
NSArray *result = [mutableSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// Alternative
NSArray *result = [[mutableSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

I wrote a quick [Obj-C test](https://gist.github.com/palmerc/014ad92fbefe7df0c94d) you can try at the command-line.

#### Run it in the background and return when finished.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    // Perform the sorting

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // Tell the main thread I'm done.

    });
});
```